# Android socket chat connection errors

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, chat

Hy! I'm adapting a chat using sockets and threads from java client to android client. The server remains the same. I've wrote the internet and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permissions in the manifest. The problem is that when I try to connect to server it throws some errors.
The `try{ socket = new Socket("localhost", 5000);}` line throws:

[link to screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/560/socketerror2.png/)

What could be the problem ? Would you want to put the whole code here ?

Comment: Thanx for the posts guys, it's working now. I was thinking the android emulator like the same machine, so the incorrect ip addressing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure that you're trying to contact your local machine and not the device itself. The phone will address itself using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. So when your device is not a server and is not listening for that port the connection will fail.

Try to use `10.0.2.2`. This should target your machine you're developing on. ([source](http://www.droidnova.com/ever-tried-localhost-with-the-android-emulator,102.html))

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the real network ip of your machine (sth. like 192.168.0.1) instead of "localhost"? The error itself looks to me like there's nobody listening on port 5000. So I guess the Droid is trying to connect to itself instead to the server.